# Outlook Office 2007 when I try to access out of office functionality it fails. If I access out of office via the web interface it works

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-office-2007

When I try to access the 'Out Of Office Functionality' in Microsoft Office Basic Outlook 2007 I get the error message "Your AutoReply message cannot be displayed. The client operation failed."

As a work around I have to access Out Of Office via the web interface to Outlook.

I am on Windows 7 - Outlook 2007 worked fine on a previous machine under XP.

What is causing this and is there a fix?

Comment: After a quick google search Cause of the program maybe because of your Norton AV scan, try this and tell me if it works. To stop the replacement of the Out of Office message body, change the Symantec Mail Security filtering rule to filter on blank Subject and  blank Sender. This is the default setting for the filtering rule.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known bug in Exchange Server 2003.  [This MS KB article may help.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/909802)

Basically the user is running in cached mode.

[Directions from MS here on turning off cached mode.](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/turn-on-or-off-cached-exchange-mode-HP001232935.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

My company has 2 different proxy servers to access the Internet.

I had the same issue when using one of the proxy and not the other one.

Apparently Outlook 2007 does HTTP requests to access the Out-Of-Office information (and also the calendar of other attendees when scheduling a meeting). The "wrong" proxy could not reach the Exchange servers. When I switched back to the correct one, the one that could access the Exchange servers), no problem anymore. It's probably not only a proxy server name problem but also linked to a proxy PAC file with the correct information and server exclusion list.